how to field map using llama3 or groq api
How can I implement a field mapping mechanism where:

If a key in the user data matches a field from a predefined list (sent to the GROQ agent), it returns the matched field.

If no exact match is found, it returns the most similar item from the list.


Currently, the GROQ agent sometimes returns a different output from the predefined list. How can I ensure accurate mapping or similarity-based matching?
import os
import json
import pymongo
import logging
import litellm
from bson import ObjectId
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Set up MongoDB client and access the database
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
)
# litellm.set_verbose=True
db = client["ekyamchatbot"]
# orders_collection = db["WebshopOrders"]

collections = db.list_collection_names()
print(collections, 'collections')
# Set environment variables for Groq
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://api.groq.com/openai/v1"
os.environ["OPENAI_MODEL_NAME"] = "llama3-8b-8192"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "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"

# Define a Groq agent
groq_agent = Agent(
    role="query interpreter",
    goal="Interpret user fields, map them to related fields.",
    backstory="You are an AI assistant that maps fields to database keys.",
    verbose=True,
    allow_delegation=False,
    
)


gur=[
  "products",
  "product_id",
  "product_name",
  "product_sku",
  "created_at",
  "product_price",
  "scan_code",
  "quantity",
  "customer_id",
  "bundle_root_information",
  "channel_id",
  "channel_name",
  "gtin",
  "upc",
  "total_fulfillable_quantity",
  "total_committed_quantity",
  "fulfillable_inventory_items",
  "fulfillable_quantity_by_fulfillment_center",
  "updated_at",
  "product_number",
  "product_type",
  "display_name2",
  "item_category_id",
  "item_category_code",
  "blocked",
  "inventory",
  "price_includes_tax",
  "unit_cost",
  "tax_group_id",
  "tax_group_code",
  "base_unit_of_measure_id",
  "base_unit_of_measure_code",
  "general_product_posting_group_id",
  "general_product_posting_group_code",
  "inventory_posting_group_id",
  "inventory_posting_group_code",
  "product_description",
  "product_vendor",
  "currency_id",
  "currency_name",
  "asset_account_id",
  "asset_account_name",
  "atp_method_id",
  "atp_method_name",
  "auto_lead_time",
  "auto_preferred_stock_level",
  "auto_reorder_point",
  "available_to_partners",
  "average_cost",
  "base_unit",
  "bill_price_variance_acct_id",
  "bill_price_variance_acct_name",
  "bill_qty_variance_acct_id",
  "bill_qty_variance_acct_name",
  "item_class_id",
  "item_class_name",
  "cogs_account_id",
  "cogs_account_name",
  "consumption_unit",
  "copy_description",
  "cost_category_id",
  "cost_category_name",
  "cost_estimate_type_id",
  "cost_estimate_type_name",
  "cost_estimate_units",
  "costing_method_name",
  "department_id",
  "department_name",
  "dont_show_price",
  "drop_ship_expense_account_id",
  "drop_ship_expense_account_name",
  "enforce_min_qty_internally",
  "exclude_from_site_map",
  "external_id",
  "froogle_product_feed",
  "gain_loss_account_id",
  "gain_loss_account_name",
  "include_children",
  "income_account_id",
  "income_account_name",
  "internal_id",
  "is_drop_ship_item",
  "is_gco_compliant",
  "is_inactive",
  "is_lot_item",
  "is_online",
  "is_serial_item",
  "is_special_order_item",
  "manufacturer_state",
  "match_bill_to_receipt",
  "matrix_item_name_template",
  "matrix_option_custitem_psgss_product_color_id",
  "matrix_option_custitem_psgss_product_size_id",
  "matrix_type_id",
  "matrix_type_name",
  "next_tag_product_feed",
  "offer_support",
  "parent_id",
  "parent_sku",
  "preferred_location_id",
  "preferred_location_name",
  "preferred_stock_level_days",
  "purchase_unit",
  "reorder_multiple",
  "round_up_as_component",
  "safety_stock_level_days",
  "sale_unit",
  "seasonal_demand",
  "shopping_product_feed",
  "shopzilla_product_feed",
  "stock_description",
  "stock_unit",
  "supply_replenishment_method_id",
  "supply_replenishment_method_name",
  "total_value",
  "track_landed_cost",
  "transfer_price",
  "transfer_price_units",
  "units_type_id",
  "units_type_name",
  "upc_code",
  "use_bins",
  "use_marginal_rates",
  "weight_units",
  "yahoo_product_feed",
  "receiving_location_display",
  "unit_rate",
  "inventory_details",
  "handle",
  "published_at",
  "template_suffix",
  "published_scope",
  "tags",
  "status",
  "product_admin_graphql_api_id",
  "variant_details",
  "options",
  "all_images",
  "description",
  "full_description",
  "weight",
  "available",
  "image_originator_url",
  "vendor",
  "media_mail",
  "packaging",
  "length",
  "width",
  "height",
  "active",
  "wholesale_cost",
  "is_bundle",
  "packaging_type",
  "promo",
  "street_date",
  "category",
  "include_inbound_in_published",
  "returnable",
  "return_sku_match",
  "return_price_restricted",
  "request_serial_number",
  "tariff_number",
  "notify_originator_inventory",
  "product_name_with_description",
  "nmfc_code",
  "image_url",
  "hazmat",
  "hazmat_type",
  "misc",
  "ean",
  "lot_control",
  "expiration_period",
  "ship_strategy",
  "velocity",
  "case_quantity",
  "carton_quantity",
  "origin_country",
  "alcohol",
  "shippable_container",
  "replenishment_min",
  "replenishment_target",
  "low_inventory_threshold",
  "published_quantity",
  "is_featured",
  "tax_class_id",
  "reviews_count",
  "sale_price",
  "cost_price",
  "product_length",
  "short_description",
  "slug",
  "website",
  "regular_price",
  "created_at_gmt",
  "updated_at_gmt",
  "product_status",
  "publish_status",
  "catalog_visibility",
  "date_on_sale_from",
  "date_on_sale_from_gmt",
  "date_on_sale_to",
  "date_on_sale_to_gmt",
  "on_sale",
  "price_html",
  "purchasable",
  "total_sales",
  "virtual",
  "downloadable",
  "download_limit",
  "download_expiry",
  "external_url",
  "button_text",
  "tax_status",
  "manage_stock",
  "backorders",
  "backorders_allowed",
  "backordered",
  "sold_individually",
  "shipping_required",
  "shipping_taxable",
  "shipping_class",
  "shipping_class_id",
  "reviews_allowed",
  "average_rating",
  "purchase_note",
  "menu_order",
  "low_stock_amount",
  "images",
  "categories",
  "attributes",
  "related_ids",
  "upsell_ids",
  "downloads",
  "cross_sell_ids",
  "default_attributes",
  "variations",
  "grouped_products",
  "meta_data",
  "has_options",
  "post_password",
  "global_unique_id",
  "depth",
  "mpn",
  "availability",
  "url",
  "is_visible",
  "retail_price",
  "map_price",
  "product_tax_code",
  "calculated_price",
  "brand_id",
  "option_set_id",
  "option_set_display",
  "inventory_level",
  "inventory_warning_level",
  "inventory_tracking",
  "reviews_rating_sum",
  "total_sold",
  "fixed_cost_shipping_price",
  "is_free_shipping",
  "related_products",
  "warranty",
  "bin_picking_number",
  "layout_file",
  "date_last_imported",
  "search_keywords",
  "availability_description",
  "gift_wrapping_options_type",
  "gift_wrapping_options_list",
  "sort_order",
  "condition",
  "is_condition_shown",
  "order_quantity_minimum",
  "order_quantity_maximum",
  "page_title",
  "meta_keywords",
  "meta_description",
  "preorder_release_date",
  "preorder_message",
  "is_preorder_only",
  "is_price_hidden",
  "price_hidden_label",
  "base_variant_id",
  "open_graph_type",
  "open_graph_title",
  "open_graph_description",
  "open_graph_use_meta_description",
  "open_graph_use_product_name",
  "open_graph_use_image",
  "view_count",
  "is_custom_url_customizable",
  "product_updated_date",
  "product_created_date",
  "color",
  "gender",
  "size",
  "brand",
  "additional_variant_attributes",
  "visibility"
]

user=[
    "id",
    "title",
    "body_html",
    "vendor",
    "product_type",
    "created_at",
    "handle",
    "updated_at",
    "published_at",
    "template_suffix",
    "published_scope",
    "tags",
    "status",
    "admin_graphql_api_id",
    "variants",
    "options",
    "images",
    "image"
]
def generate_mongo_query(user_query, gur):
    """Generate MongoDB query using the Groq agent."""
    groq_task = Task(
        description=(
            f"You are a field-mapping agent. Map the user-provided fields {user_query} "
            f"to the provided keys: {gur}. "
            "If a key in '{user_query}' matches exactly with a key in {gur}, return it as a match. "
            "If no exact match is found, return at least 3 related suggestions based on semantic similarity. "
            "If no suggestions are possible, return: {'error': 'No matching fields found, please refine your query.'}."
        ),
        agent=groq_agent,
        top_n=1,
        expected_output=(
            "JSON response with a 'matchedKey' for exact matches "
            "or {'suggestions': ['<related_key1>', '<related_key2>', '<related_key3>']} for semantic matches. "
            "Always use double quotes for JSON keys and values."
        ),
    )

    crew = Crew(
        agents=[groq_agent],
        tasks=[groq_task],
        verbose=True,
        process=Process.sequential,
    )

    output = crew.kickoff().__dict__.get("raw")
    if not output:
        raise ValueError("Invalid output format from Groq Agent.")
    
    try:
        parsed_output = json.loads(output)
        return parsed_output
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Error decoding JSON from Groq Agent: {e}")



How do you define "most similar"?  There are a hundred ways to determine that.  What failures have you seen, exactly?  A plain text search might be fooled by "backorders" and "backorders_allowed".
